# How to make grouped and stacked line plots using two dataframes?

Tags: r, plot, stacked

I have two data sets, one is for males and one for females. They both have 4 variables, which are: Year, DK, SE NO. So they both looks like this (of course just with different values):

[image: example of data set]

I want to make line plots for Males and Females stacked and grouped into contries, DK SE and NO. So it can be stacked plots, like this:

[image: idea of plot]

Comment: Please post data as copy/pasteable code, not a pictures. Have you tried to make the plots on your own? Where did you get stuck? I would suggest trying `ggplot2` with facets by sex.

Comment: We have a [nice tutorial for minimal working examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I suggest you to read, before posting actually. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us what your data frames are called, but let's call them `men` and `women`. As long as they both have *exactly* the same columns (including names), you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

men %>% 
  mutate(Sex = "Men") %>%
  bind_rows(women %>% mutate(Sex = "Women")) %>%
  pivot_longer(c("DK", "SE", "NO")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Sex~.) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Made up data with same structure as question data**

```r
set.seed(1)

men <- data.frame(Year = 1995:2022,
           DK = 35 + cumsum(rnorm(28)),
           SE = 40 + cumsum(rnorm(28)),
           NO = 38 + cumsum(rnorm(28)))

women <- data.frame(Year = 1995:2022,
           DK = 35 + cumsum(rnorm(28)),
           SE = 40 + cumsum(rnorm(28)),
           NO = 38 + cumsum(rnorm(28)))
```

Comment: @rr19 I'm guessing one or more of your columns are character rather than numeric. Try changing `aes(Year`  to `aes(as.numeric(Year)`

Comment: But it would be better not to guess. It's really hard to help when you use images of data rather than copy/paste able text, which is easy to do.